# Marshmallow with SQLite Binding data taking too much time

Tags: android, sqlite, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have created one Database with 25+ tables and its working fine since last two years.

Recently I have upgraded my app with build version of **Marshmallow**.

After upgrading, Marshmallow devices takes too much time to bind data after execution of query.

I am calling query like:

```
productCursor = dbHelper.getProduct(brandId, categoryId, searchString, isSortCategoryWise, nextItems);
```

By calling this method, It prints log quickly but returning value after taking too much time.

**My Query is:**

```
"SELECT " +
"p." + PRODUCT_ID + ", " +
"p." + PRODUCT_SERVER_ID + ", " +
"p." + PRODUCT_CODE + ", " +
"p." + PRODUCT_NAME + ", " +
"p." + PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION + ", " +
"p." + PRODUCT_RATE + ", " +
"p." + PRODUCT_DISCOUNT + ", " +
"p." + PRODUCT_BUNDLE_QTY + ", " +
"p." + PRODUCT_STOCK + ", " +
"p." + PRODUCT_OFFER_DISCOUNT + ", " +
"p." + PRODUCT_IS_NEW + ", " +
"(SELECT " +
" pi." + PRODUCT_IMAGE_URL +
" FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCT_IMAGE + " pi " +
" WHERE pi." + PRODUCT_IMAGE_BIT + "=1 AND pi." + PRODUCT_IMAGE_PRODUCT_ID
+ "=p." + PRODUCT_SERVER_ID +
") url " +
" FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCT + " p " +
" INNER JOIN " + TABLE_PRODUCT_TO_CAT + " ptc ON p." + PRODUCT_SERVER_ID
+ "=ptc." + PRODUCT_TO_CATEGORY_PRODUCT_ID + " AND ptc.status=0 " +
innerJoin +
" WHERE " +
"p." + PRODUCT_STATUS + "=0 AND " +
"ptc." + PRODUCT_TO_CATEGORY_CATEGORY_ID + "=? ORDER BY " + orderBy,
new String[] { Integer.toString(category_id) });
```

I don't think so that is problem in Query because it's working fine with Lower Level Devices than MarshMallow.

Is there any problem with Marshmallow and SQLite?

Anyone faced this problem, Help please. :)

Thanks in advance with Appreciation.

Answer (score -2):

*I think mySql is easier than this. if u use mySql maybe you can dont get a problem I check the codes but nothing wrong use mySql...*

**Edit: I am trying to say: if you use mysql maybe the error would vanish. but as you stated you don't have an option. The problem is that the code is pretty messed up, there could be a plus (+) or quotation mark (") problem and maybe you misspeled some of the column names. For future programmers I suggest that you use object oriented mysql from ADO.NET. (there is a small chance that you can use SQL too)**

**Example: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/introduce-entity-framework-with-ado-net-entity-data-model/**

**With this you automatically get rid of sql injection problems too.
Hope this answer is better :).**

**Don't code harder, code smarter. If you use this you will have more time for coding. You won't waste time with checking any kind of typing errors.**

Comment: I used SQLite for local database for offline access, So I have to use SQLite only.